# Pytorch neural network for classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

The task is to train a neural network to choose the value **v** in a list for given input **x** that minimizes **(x - v)**.
For example I have 100x1 dimension tensor of integers as input. My neural network should output probability distribution for those values.

It works properly for 1x1 tensor, but outputs the same distribution for each example in the input. I want it to output proper distribution for every example separately. How should I fix that?

Here is the code:

```
N, D_in, D_out, H = 20, 1, 5, 10
X = torch.LongTensor(100, 1).random_(0, 500).float()
values = torch.FloatTensor([0, 1, 3, 5, 100])

model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(D_in, H),
    nn.Sigmoid(),
    nn.Linear(H, D_out),
    nn.Softmax(dim=1)
)

def loss_function(x, y, probability):
    return torch.mean(torch.sum(probability*((x-y)**2), 1).div(probability.size(1)))

loss_fn = loss_function
learning_rate = 1e-3
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

model.train(True)
for epoch in range(200):
    pred = model(X)
    loss = loss_fn(X, values, pred)
    print('loss: ', loss.item())
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

And it is the input and the output for 20 examples:
Input:

```
tensor([[ 16.],
         [ 28.],
         [188.],
         [ 16.],
         [379.],
         [366.],
         [366.],
         [421.],
         [ 13.],
         [ 86.],
         [ 38.],
         [135.],
         [173.],
         [153.],
         [223.],
         [133.],
         [316.],
         [108.],
         [133.],
         [295.]])
```

Output:

```
tensor([[1.2926e-04, 1.3165e-04, 1.2761e-04, 1.3385e-04, 9.9948e-01],
         [9.9158e-05, 1.0086e-04, 9.8492e-05, 1.0170e-04, 9.9960e-01],
         [3.3826e-05, 3.4437e-05, 3.4443e-05, 3.2122e-05, 9.9987e-01],
         [1.2926e-04, 1.3165e-04, 1.2761e-04, 1.3385e-04, 9.9948e-01],
         [3.3173e-05, 3.3778e-05, 3.3758e-05, 3.1419e-05, 9.9987e-01],
         [3.3175e-05, 3.3780e-05, 3.3759e-05, 3.1421e-05, 9.9987e-01],
         [3.3175e-05, 3.3780e-05, 3.3759e-05, 3.1421e-05, 9.9987e-01],
         [3.3170e-05, 3.3775e-05, 3.3754e-05, 3.1416e-05, 9.9987e-01],
         [1.4026e-04, 1.4281e-04, 1.3817e-04, 1.4524e-04, 9.9943e-01],
         [4.4578e-05, 4.5341e-05, 4.5195e-05, 4.3355e-05, 9.9982e-01],
         [8.1636e-05, 8.2994e-05, 8.1468e-05, 8.2810e-05, 9.9967e-01],
         [3.5991e-05, 3.6629e-05, 3.6643e-05, 3.4392e-05, 9.9986e-01],
         [3.4158e-05, 3.4773e-05, 3.4784e-05, 3.2472e-05, 9.9986e-01],
         [3.4881e-05, 3.5505e-05, 3.5521e-05, 3.3232e-05, 9.9986e-01],
         [3.3425e-05, 3.4031e-05, 3.4026e-05, 3.1694e-05, 9.9987e-01],
         [3.6153e-05, 3.6794e-05, 3.6807e-05, 3.4561e-05, 9.9986e-01],
         [3.3191e-05, 3.3796e-05, 3.3777e-05, 3.1439e-05, 9.9987e-01],
         [3.9212e-05, 3.9897e-05, 3.9870e-05, 3.7751e-05, 9.9984e-01],
         [3.6153e-05, 3.6794e-05, 3.6807e-05, 3.4561e-05, 9.9986e-01],
         [3.3207e-05, 3.3812e-05, 3.3795e-05, 3.1457e-05, 9.9987e-01]],
        grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward>)
```

Comment: What are you predicting with your model exactly ? You're comparing `X` and `values` but those two tensors are constants in your whole training. Your prediction is used as a multiplicative factor to their difference. Your network will only try to make a prediction as close to zero as possible when `X` is very different from `values`. Of course the predicted values would be the same every time in this situation. 
Also, does the code run as you wrote it ? It seems to me that the difference `x - y` in your loss function doesn't work because your tensors have incompatible sizes.

Comment: @Sunreef My model predicts probability distribution over `values` in list. Yeah, the code runs properly. `x-y` where `x` is 20x1, `y` is 1x5, equals tensor of size 20x5.

Comment: I believe your loss function needs to be redesigned. To optimize weights of the network, the gradients of loss with respect to the weights need to calculated. And from the chain rule, we can see the gradients have a factor, which is the gradients of loss wight respect to `predictions`, which are constants. So your optimizer are not actually working and you can see your loss is not actually decreasing.

Comment: I changed optimizer to Adam. It works now.